# best way to execute unix commands within a perl script and to check if it failed

Tags: perl

I want to execute a couple of unix commands within perl. What's the best way to do so?
Is it better to use qx or system()? Is there a good way to check if it fails? Can someone show me a good example? Thanks.

```
my $crflag=qx('/bin/touch /tmp/flag.done');
my $chgperm=qx('chmod 755 /tmp/flag.done');
```

vs.

```
my $crflag = '/bin/touch /tmp/flag.done';
my $chgperm ='chmod 755 /tmp/flag.done';
system ($crflag);
system ($chgperm);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

- You don't seem to want the output, meaning you'd want `system`, but these are very simple steps and should probably be done directly in Perl, instead of calling out to the shell.  `touch` is literally 1 call in Perl (2 if you count closing the file.)
- There is a race condition, since you're creating the file, and then setting its permissions in two steps.  Since this looks like a flag file, a race condition seems relevant, and thus you probably want an atomic create/setperms in one command.
- Since it's a flag *file*, you probably want mode `0644` instead of `0755`.

In Perl, you can solve all of the above with something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Fcntl qw( :DEFAULT );   # Core module, for O_CREAT, etc. constants
use strict;
use warnings;

# You probably want 0644, as a flag file probably shouldn't be executable..?
sysopen( my $fh, '/tmp/flag.done', O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_RDWR, 0644 )
# Sysopen returns a undef if unsuccessful, with an error message stored in $!
    or die "$!";
# write to it here, if you need to.
close( $fh );
```

You can place this into a sub with whatever arguments you want to create a (much more) atomic creation step to avoid other processes interfering between the large number of calls to shell out twice to create the file and then reset its permissions.  (There's still concerns with synchronization, so it could still be pre-empted, but this is overall a far better solution.)

There are other flags you may wish to use.  Check `perldoc perlopentut` and search for `sysopen` for a small list, or check `perldoc Fcntl` and your platform's documentation for a more comprehensive list.  You may also wish to change the `0644` permissions to something more and less restrictive, and you may further wish to use locking; see `perldoc -f flock` for information and code samples on advisory locking.

Comment: @Sdaz- Thanks for your reply. I'm not familiar with `Fnctl` and am looking this up. At some point this flag is going to be read from a separate program as an indicator to start up its process. So yes, its just a flag file.

Comment: `Fcntl` is just there because it exports the constants `O_CREAT`, `O_EXCL`, etc.  `sysopen` is a core perl function and is available without it, but it's easier to use with the constants.  The above should get you started; but note that `O_EXCL` won't overwrite the file if it already exists; get rid of it if you want it to be able to.  The description in `perldoc perlopentut` (under `sysopen`) is possibly more thorough on what each constant does.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the fact that both operations can be done trivially using builtins `utime` and `chmod`, [IPC::System::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3A%3ASystem%3A%3ASimple) provides error checking.

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw( system );
system('/bin/touch /tmp/flag.done');
system('chmod 755 /tmp/flag.done');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) along with `$?`. Try to avoid using `qx` when the output is not required.

```
system '/bin/touch /tmp/flag.done';
my $touch_status = $? >> 8;

system 'chmod 755 /tmp/flag.done';
my $chmod_status = $? >> 8;
```

Comment: thanks for your input. I did a print to `$touch_status` and `$chmod_status`, both returning 0 which means no error. So to check success, would i do something like `if $touch_status == 0 { print "flag is set";}` ?

Comment: I would say we get much better control using `IPC::Run`